# Excel Formula Solution Required

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking for a solution to the following issue and I just don't have the expertise.
I have a column of dates and beside that column I have a column of numbers.
I would like a formula that would add up the numbers until I hit a certain threshold (designated number)
For example let's just say I have 9 rows in column B all with 100 and beside each number in the column A is a date.  I would like to know which date in column A represents a Number in column B that is equal to or less than 750
Obviously it will be row 7 but I need the formula.
Thanks in advance and looking forward to any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(750,SUMIF(OFFSET(B1,0,0,(ROW(B1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))))),"<>0")))
```

Depending on one's version this is an array formula and may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: WOW...you are amazing and the CTRL+SHFT+Enter was needed. Thank you thank you thank you. I would like to know the logic behind it but that worked beautifully.

Comment: The `(ROW(B1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))))` creates an array of number from `1` to the number of values in column B.  That is passed to the `height` argument in the OFFSET making an array of ranges `B1`, `B1:B2`,`B1:B3` and so on.  That array is passed to the SUMIFS which then returns a array of the sums: `100`,`200`,`300` and so on to the MATCH, the MATCH then finds where the 750 falls in that array and returns the relative number to the INDEX which then returns the value in Column A at that index.

Comment: BTW, Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that to me.  I did check mark the answer. You really know your stuff and I appreciate you taking the time to solve this for me.